# Multithread with workerpool modul

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, pool

```
import os
import urllib
import workerpool

from datetime import datetime

class DownloadJob(workerpool.Job):    

    def __init__(self, fa):
       self.fa = fa 

    def run(self):        
       f = open(self.fa + '.txt','w')
       f.write('Example Note.......')
       f.close()  


pool = workerpool.WorkerPool(size=5)

def workfile():        
    range1 = 51
    range2 = 102
    fam1 = 555
    fam2 = 833

    ranges = range2 -range1
    fams = fam2 -fam1
    workname = "Python"

    path = os.getcwd()

    os.system('mkdir ' + str(workname))
    sTime = datetime.now()

    for a in range(ranges + 1):
        os.chdir(path + '\\' + str(workname))
        os.system('mkdir ' + str(range1 + a))
        os.chdir(path + '\\' + str(workname) + '\\' + str(range1 + a))

        for b in range(fams + 1):
            fa = str(fam1 + b)
            job = DownloadJob(fa)
            pool.put(job)
            pool.shutdown()
            pool.wait()                                              

        print 'Elapsed Time: %s' % (datetime.now() - sTime)

        z = open('info.txt','w')
        z.write('Elapsed Time: %s' % (datetime.now() - sTime))
        z.close()

    os.chdir(path + '\\' + str(workname))

    tumSure = open('info.txt','w')
    tumSure.write('Elapsed All Time: %s' % (datetime.now() - sTime))
    tumSure.close()

    print 'All Time: %s' % (datetime.now() - sTime)        
    print 'Workname : %s downloaded.' % (workname)

    quit()

workfile()
```

Hi all,

I have a code as above and I want to use thread logic for creating file. Folder numbers start wird `range1`, i.e. 51. Text files are created in this directory with the names `555.txt` to `833.txt`. But after creating the folder with name `52` it stops, failing to create `555.txt` to `833.txt`.

it think it stops because

```
pool.shutdown()
pool.wait()
```

How can I make the loop continue with no stop?

Comment: i didnt understand os.mkdir() exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should only shutdown the pool if you are finished with it, i.e. after the `for a` loop, maybe even in a `try...finally` clause.

It would look that way:

```
try:
    for a in range(ranges + 1):
        os.chdir(path + '\\' + str(workname))
        os.system('mkdir ' + str(range1 + a))
        os.chdir(path + '\\' + str(workname) + '\\' + str(range1 + a))

        for b in range(fams + 1):
            fa = str(fam1 + b)
            job = DownloadJob(fa)
            pool.put(job)
finally:
    pool.shutdown()
    pool.wait()
```

In this way the `pool` shutdown

a) happens only if all pool putting is done and
b) happens even if there is an exception in order to cleanly shutdown.

If the pool had a context manager, it would be even simpler. But AFAICS, [it hasn't](https://github.com/shazow/workerpool/blob/master/workerpool/pools.py). 
Otherwise, you could do

```
with pool:
    for a in range(ranges + 1):
        os.chdir(path + '\\' + str(workname))
        os.system('mkdir ' + str(range1 + a))
        os.chdir(path + '\\' + str(workname) + '\\' + str(range1 + a))

        for b in range(fams + 1):
            fa = str(fam1 + b)
            job = DownloadJob(fa)
            pool.put(job)
```

But if you want, you can do

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def shutdown_wait(pool):
    try:
        yield pool
    finally:
        pool.shutdown()
        pool.wait()

...
with shutdown_wait(pool):
    for a ... [as above]
```